# Extract link text from a with webscraping using Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I have the following `<html>` text:

`<a href="link.html" target="_parent">Text</a>`

How should I do for getting "Text" value?  I am trying with this, but I get an empty value:

`=INDEX(importxml("http://www.remoteurl.com";"//a[@href='link.html']");1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it properly, but the problem is that coding was inside an iframe, so it was impossible to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your syntax and it worked for me. I shortened it a little for testing purposes.

```
=importxml("https://www.remoteurl.com","//a[@href='link.html']")
```

Be sure that the `href` value you are passing in the xpath query is exactly what is present on the web page, e.g. if the web page uses a relative path then you must also use the same relative path.